# PHP mySQL 404 function

Tags: php, mysql

The following function is designed to check whether this row in this tables exists. I know that it does not yet whether I `$row` or !`$row` the if function it does not do anything.

```
function four_zero_four($name){
    $four_zero_four = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pages WHERE name = '$name'"); 

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($four_zero_four)) { 
      echo 'no'; die(); 
    }
};
```

`$name` is the name field from the row and is working correctly in other functions.

Comment: you might need to escape the variable, considering that you are using the old mysql_* functions

Comment: also, even if it isn't a solution, you could consider using mysql_num_rows to test if the query would fetch any results instead of really fetching them considering that you are not using the data; an alternative would also be to run a count and not fetch all the results

Comment: My mistake.. $row contained nothing..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to check whether a row exists is by using the mysql_result function in conjunction with the `COUNT` function as such:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(1) FROM `table` WHERE `field` = 'something'");
$result = mysql_result($query, 0);
```

When you now print out the `$result` variable, you will see the amount of rows that are actually being returned by the query. This is generally faster than using `mysql_num_rows`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the logic, aren't you printing "no"; die() when there IS a row found, instead of when now row is found?  Either way, here's how I would check:

```
function four_zero_four($name){
    $four_zero_four = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pages WHERE name = '$name'"); 

    if (mysql_num_rows($four_zero_four) == 0) {
        // ROW DOES NOT EXIST
    } else {
        // ROW EXISTS
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not work because it wont even be executed if there is no row returned by your query.

Use `mysql_num_rows()` instead:

```
$count = mysql_num_rows($four_zero_four);

if($count <= 0){
    die("no rows in this table!");
}
```

Also, you should maybe consider to use MYSQLi commands instead of the old `mysql_query()` implementation and `SELECT *`, as they are deprecated.